# Is ATG DMS true JMS implementation

Tags: jms, atg

It looks like ATG's implementation of JMS is achieved through scheduler whereby it polls database in specific interval through SqlJmsProvider component. I do agree that ATG's DMS does provide with all JMS feature like Queue, Topic, Durable Subscribers, Retry etc... but isin't using a scheduler to poll the DB to send ATG Order to Fulfillment an overkill ?  (too many queries fired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ATG Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s1203atgandjms01.html) it explains that there are two JMS providers available within ATG:

- SQL JMS
- Local JMS

The difference between the two are:

Local JMS is Synchronous and extremely fast. It runs within a single transaction and is bound to a single process, thus when sending a message, it blocks while waiting for an acknowledgement. SQL JMS on the otherhand, is Asynchronous and can be used across processes (thus an order submission on Commerce can be processed on Fulfillment). SQL JMS is non-blocking so once the message is put on the queue, the requesting process can continue. This also means that Commerce can continue running, even if Fulfillment is down. The messages are also persisted in SQL JMS while they are stateless and lost during a restart for Local JMS.

Using the scheduler to poll the queue is an acceptable solution and most of the older asynchronous message queues implemented this solution. In [IBM MQ Version 7](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/v7/) performance has been improved by reducing the amount of polling while using [IBM WAS Version 6](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cmj_ovrvw.html) for example the solution is also based on regular polling of the queue.

So no, polling the database on a scheduled interval is not an overkill.

Comment: My understanding is that Batch & JMS are designed for different purposes.So was wondering if using a scheduler approach to poll for Order (in order to send to fulfillment) is the best approach used by ATG. I ask this because in one of the projects - we did not use the Fulfillment module & instead had a custom scheduler poll for orders and then send it to Fulfillment.

Comment: So Commerce needs to speak to another system via some Message Queue, right? If I understand your reference to 'JMS' vs. 'Batch' correctly you assume the JMS approach to be 'synchronous'? So Commerce will be blocking until it gets a response from the Fulfillment System. This all works on a 'push' system. By using 'Batch' processing you become Asynchronous and Commerce can continue. Fulfillment will process messages by 'pulling' them off the queue. Most messaging systems work in an Asynchronous fashion and have to poll the queue in some way to know whether to process any messages.

Comment: I am sorry if my description is vague. I am just not able to find a reason to use ATG's JMS vs just the scheduler to send data to fulfillment. My fulfillment is just a webservice invocation and I don't  mind polling the DB using a scheduler for orders instead of using DMS mechanism to achieve the same thing. Because, using DMS, I just add load to the DB (messages) and the message sink will anyways have to invoke the fulfillment webservice.

Comment: You are right. You've been a bit vague as I understood your question to be 'why would you poll the database from a scheduler to check for messages'. Your approach would be fine, though 'adding load to the DB' for the sort of query you expect to do with DMS is minuscule so that shouldn't be your deciding factor. Ease of implementation, extendibility and maintenance should.