# ATG scheduler/Queue Manager

Tags: java, atg, oracle-commerce

ATG scheduler creates the scheduled job and executes it. If the job is in scheduler's thread other jobs have to wait. What I want to do is use ATG scheduler to create the job, pass to queue manager so that it executes one after other not stopping the scheduler all together. so I want to put a queue between scheduler creating the job and scheduler executing that same job. 
Can this be done? or there is a way where all my jobs will use same thread that's not scheduler's thread?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a Dynamo Messaging System (aka PatchBay) queue in combination with a scheduler.

Something along the lines of:

1. Scheduler runs and uses a `MessageSource` to put a jms messages on a queue for each job *This ensures that the scheduler does not have to "wait" as it simply creates jms messages for each job.*
2. Create and configure a nucleus component `JobMessageListener` which implements the `onMessage` event and reads the jobs off the queue and delegates the work to another service.  *This ensures that the job fire up automatically and are processed in order as it is using a jms queue.*
3. Create and configure a nucleus component, something along the lines of `JobProcessorService` which does the heavy lifting and processes the jobs.

You do not mention which version of ATG however for ATG 10.2 the instructions for achieving this can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s1207messagingcomponents01.html).

Comment: Please also refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098202/is-atg-dms-true-jms-implementation/21106733#21106733) which talks about synchronous vs asynchronous messaging in ATG.

Answer (score 0):

You can control whether the job executes in its own thread or the schedulers thread if you are  scheduling the job with the scheduler yourself via the `schedulder.addScheduledJob(...)` method. The `threadMethod` property of `ScheduledJob` has three possible settings which are discussed in the link below.

[ScheduledJob Thread Methods - Documentation Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0905scheduledjobthreadmethods01.html)

Basically, you have:

- **SCHEDULER_THREAD**: Job runs using the schedulers thread.
- **SEPARATE_THREAD**: Scheduler creates a new thread for each execution of
  the job and the job runs in that thread.
- **REUSED_THREAD**: Same as **SEPERATE_METHOD** except that the same thread is used across multiple runs of the job.

So, it sounds like you would want to use either **SEPARATE_THREAD** or **REUSED_THREAD**.

```
public void doStartService() throws ServiceException
{
    ScheduledJob job = new ScheduledJob("hello",
                                        "Prints Hello",
                                        getAbsoluteName(),
                                        getSchedule(),
                                        this,
                                        ScheduledJob.SEPARATE_THREAD);
    jobId = getScheduler().addScheduledJob(job);
}
```

If you're creating a job that extends from either `SchedulableService` or `SingletonSchedulableService` then you can configure the  `threadMethodString` property of your component to have a value of either `scheduler`, `separate`, or `reused` and therefore avoid the custom coding shown above. By default it is set to `reused`.

For example:

```
# /my/custom/MyScheduledJob
$class=my.custom.MyScheduledJob
$scope=global
threadMethodString=separate
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is you would have to code it very carefully to ensure you do not duplicate any work across threads as then you will end up with lots of contention.